# Opencart to build phonegap android application

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, opencart

I would like to build a phonegap android app for a shopping site build using `Opencart` in php and mySql.

I know I can not use php in developing android phonegap app, it has to be html and jquery. I don't have any knowledge in PHP and also have no idea how the existing shopping site is done. Only thing I know about existing site is it is using Opencart API. And also no idea about Opencart.

Is there any way by which I can use ajax calls from PHP site in my phonegap app? That way I would be using same functionality as it is in existing site in new mobile app.

Please provide me any tutorials or articles present on this topic.

**Edit:**

I tried make a ajax call from the mobile just to check if I get response back, but it doesn't work as it becomes a `Cross Domain Ajax Call`.

Also would like to know about the ajax calls in opencart. How is the response of these ajax calls? Does it return HTML or json response?

Comment: OpenCart uses as few AJAX requests as possible. Those are: add/remove a product to/from cart, add a product to wishlist, add a product to compare, add a review, the checkout process (certain steps). Period. (I may have missed one or two, but I hope you got the point.) Each other request is just common synchronous HTTP GET or POST. BTW, what is wrong with sticking around with OpenCart, exploring all those requests and building your own AJAX ones? OpenCart is build on MVC pattern, therefore each public method in controller can be invoked by any HTTP request - using the correct route.

Comment: I didn't get your point `what is wrong with sticking around with OpenCart, exploring all those requests and building your own AJAX ones?`

Comment: Do you mean I can use Opencart for building phonegap android app?

Comment: Yes, I do, yes, I do...

Comment: How do I do that? Will I need to download api extention?

Comment: If I try to make ajax call from mobile, the request cannot pass through as it becomes `Cross Domain ajax call`.

Comment: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=17982&filter_search=api Check this out

Comment: *If I try to make ajax call from mobile, the request cannot pass through as it becomes Cross Domain ajax call* => https://www.google.com/search?q=phonegap%20cross%20domain%20ajax

Comment: As for your question in edit - the response would be most of the time the HTML. I understand this is not expected response. For this purpose you would need to build a whole new API for OpenCart returning XMLs or JSON. This could be written as a standalone one in Java looking directly to the OpenCart's DB (as you are mentioning no knowledge of PHP).

Comment: Thanks @shadyyx, so writing my own webservice would work? I could do in asp.net

Comment: Of course. You can write in whatever language you want if you can reach a DB from it and it is accessible to phonegap app.

Comment: Develop a opencart application without technical knowledge is in contus M Comm. It is a readymade mobile commerce solution for all platforms. Just implement in your website & sync your store with advanced features.